# how to insert, update and delete Calendar and events

Tags: android, calendar

is there any way to add, delete and update Calendar.
and 
is there any way to add, delete and update Events in Calendar.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to interface with Google Calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976927/android-how-to-interface-with-google-calendar)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

check this code
http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java
it may help u
:)

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: selected (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name FROM Calendars WHERE (selected=1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Calendar GData API, as is discussed on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976927/android-how-to-interface-with-google-calendar).

Comment: Hi, I like to list all available calendars in my device and allow  users to do all tasks (Create , update Delete Events). So its going to be all other  device calendars and Google calendars will be available. Then what's the best method do I can manage all of this with Android Calendar API, or do i have to use GDATA API for Google Calendars(Calendar listed in device with users mail).Please give me a direction..which one is right?

Answer (score 0):

it is also not possible through gdata libraries.
http://www.anddev.org/gdata_api_problem-t3427.html

Answer (score 0):

you can you use GoogleApiJavaClient
see here why :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient

look here for more resource
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/