# get events of default calendar in my custom calendar in android?

Tags: android, calendar

Can i get all the events and other informations from android device default calendar in my custom calender please suggest me some tutorial or any example for this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Android Calendar Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events) and then you can add events to your calendar using ContentValues smth like that [Read and write Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101576/read-and-write-calendar)