# Can I create or delete an Android calendar from a custom application?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to make an application that manages the internal Android calendar, but I want to know if I can delete or create new calendars. (I know about the calendar's events but not about the calendars.) Can you help me with examples or documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code on how to read calendars and their events [here](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151). You should also be able to write to the Calendar ContentProvider.

But remember there is no official Calendar API. Any code working today or on a certain device can break in the future or on other devices.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3101359/821894)

Comment: I saw this documentation before, but I need to know how to delete and create Calendars, not events. Thanks anyway.